# Can't commit using Git Bash

Tags: git

I am brand new to Git and am running into an issue where I see a red "M" next to several files that I've modified when using 'git status -s'.  However, when I attempt to commit (git commit -m "some stuff") these changes, they are ignored.  I'm sure this is something simple, but I haven't been able to google my way to an answer.

Comment: Try reading a guide on getting started in Git like this one: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: Thanks.  I had been following along with a tutorial, but it seems it was glossing over some of the fundamental information.  The guide you linked to seems to be much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to do a

```
git add .
```

to add your modifications to the index, then commit.

[image: http://www.tigraine.at/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/image6.png]

See [`git add` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> The "index" holds a snapshot of the content of the working tree, and it is this snapshot that is taken as the contents of the next commit.
>   Thus after making any changes to the working directory, and before running the commit command, you must use the `add` command to add any new or modified files to the index.

Try and follow the **[GitHub training session](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)** to see that command in action in the **[step 3](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/3)**.

[image: git add]

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks for the links to the tutorials as well.